# How can I create a random sequence generater in php which have arithmatic oeration like addition and substraction?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am ataching a screenshot of my form with some input given by user.

in the screenshot as you can see user have given an input for first field i.e.no of question
for 2nd field i.e no.of series
for 3rd field i.e no.of digits 
and finally user selected 3 operations
so after clicking  generate button the expected output will be ans of the generated seq.)
the above generated seq having random operands and operators generated.
so, how can I generate this type of output for any input like this given by user?
[image: screenshot of form with some user input]this is my form from where user will give his input and accordingly in output a random sequence having operands at even position and operators at odd position and at last the calculation of that respective sequence will be shown. how can I do that using arrays of for loops?

below is form that i have created

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     Select no.of questions:<input type="number" name="que" value="que">
    <br><br>
    Select no. of series: <select name="select_box">
    <option value="0"> 2 </option>
    <option value="1"> 3 </option>
    <option value="2"> 4 </option>
    <option value="3"> 5 </option>
    <option value="4"> 6 </option>
    <option value="5"> 7 </option>
    <option value="6"> 8 </option>
    <option value="7"> 9 </option>
    <option value="8"> 10 </option>
    </select>
   <br><br>
   Select number type(in digits) :
   <select name="select_box">
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1"> 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> 3 </option>
   <br><br>
   </select>
   <br /><br />
  Select operations:<br />
 <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation" value="addition"> 
 <label>Addition</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation" value="subtract"> 
 <label>Subtraction</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation" value="multiply"> 
 <label>Multiplication</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation" value="divide"> 
 <label>Division</label>
  <br><br>
  <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
    <br>
      </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the how to ask section of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just FYI, you do not need PHP for this, unless you are using any database values down the line. You can do this entirely by JavaScript alone. I would look into `append` in JavaScript. The algorythm etc. for how your application should work is up to you.